# Library path error in Java

Tags: java, dll

The exact error message reads as following:

```
Library Path not specified in properties file.
     Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
     jni_interface.driver.start([Ljava/lang/String;)V
            at jni_interface.driver.start(Native Method)
            at gui.MainFrame$2.run(MainFrame.java:501)
```

I have tried installing JRE and JDK,both 64 and 32 bit versions(it is is a 64bit machine running windows server 2003).
I have specified the path to the bin directories for both JRE and JDK in environment variables.
I also use have mingW.

Do I need to specify the path to "jvm.dll" which is present in the bin\Client folder?What is the problem?

Suggestions will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Did you call `System.loadLibrary` with the filename of your DLL?

Comment: No, I haven't. The error that I am getting is when I try to run a prototype tool;
I run it from the command prompt using the following command:
>java -jar x.jar

how do i call System.loadlibrary?
@immibis

Comment: I was assuming this was a program you wrote, since you didn't say what is not working, just "I get this error".